# What is the expiration date of a domain?

Tags: whois, domainexpiration

When I get the WHOIS records of a domain, it contains an expiration date. So I was  wondering what is the expiration date of a domain? How this date has been set? What will happen to the domain after it gets expired? Who set this date?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this question was probably more appropriate for [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) since it is more about general computing, and not about development or programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network Solutions [provides a breakdown](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/domain-deletion-policy/) of what happens during expiration and deletion periods.

In short, from the page:

> If an expired domain name registration is not renewed during any grace period provided by us, pursuant to our Service Agreement, rather than delete the domain name registration, we may, in our sole discretion, renew and transfer the domain name registration to Network Solutions or to a third party on the customer’s behalf.

Comment: But this all depend on the TLD involved, no 2 registries do the same... And it would be better to link to registries documentations and not registrars one.

Answer (score 0):

When the owner can not renew the domain in the grace period, the domain would be available to public and anyone can get it base on first come first serve.